Как сделать сортировку товаров по цене\названию и пр. в django
подскажите или подкиньте информации может, никак не могу сообразить.
Есть сайт, на нем есть страница с отображением всех продуктов из одной категории, которая формируется посредством передачи слага общего для продуктов которые нужно отобразить
<a href="{% url 'product_info' product.slug %}"

Дальше все передается в ListView класс
path('products/<slug:prod_slug>/', ProductListView.as_view(), name='products'),

Затем в классе формируем контекст
class ProductListView(ListView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'products.html'
    context_object_name = 'products'
    extra_context = {'title': 'Therapy'}

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Product.objects.filter(category__slug=self.kwargs['prod_slug'])

Суть в том что на итоговой странице мне нужна сортировка товаров по цене, как это сделать? Я понимаю что вроде это через get параметры передается, но не могу сообразить как их передать в этот же url?
